# simplyfying a mathematical expression

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to calculate the value of below expression where $M$ is 1000000007 (prime) and $N$ can be any large number $\le 1000$?

\[\frac{N!}{(N/2)!(N/2)!} \mathbin{\%} M\]

It is possible to simplify it like 
\[\frac{(N/2 + 1)(N/2 + 2)\cdots N}{(N/2)!}\]
but then $(N/2)!$ is still a huge number to calculate.

Now can also simply it further like `(n/2 + 1)*(n/2 + 2)...*(n-1)`/`3*4...(n/2-1)`. But this still isn't enough.

Is it possible to break it down further?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The simplest way to calculate factorial is the way you stated above. This is obviously from an algorithm problem that tackles the overflow of the `factorial` function. But to attract good responses to your question, you need to explain what you want exactly.

Comment: this is actually in reference to quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736514/optimising-code-for-modular-arithmetic and this is an algorithm problem.

Comment: could you include the reference in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is needed here is **[Modular Multiplicative Inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)** i.e. $x$ i sthe multiplicative inverse of a iff $$ax \equiv aa^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod m$$
The multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $m$ exists if and only if $a$ and $m$ are coprime, so if $m$ is prime then every number that is not a multiple of $m$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $m$.

To solve the problem $ax \equiv 1 \mod m \implies ax-mk=1| k\in \mathbb Z$, since our problem satisfies  **[Bézout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)** ($a$ and $m$ are coprime.) one can apply **[Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)**. You can find the algorithm in Python code **[here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)**.

To compute $\cfrac {n!}{a!\times b!}$ modulo $m$, you can rewrite this as $n!\times(a!)^{-1}\times(b!)^{-1}$. As long as none of $a,\ b,\ $or $n$ is greater $m$, then there shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: And if any of $a,b,n$ are greater than $m$, [Lucas's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) applies since $m$ is prime.